# Missing argument in PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need some help.

Im trying to get some records from a table using dates, setting start and end dates from 2 inputs, my english is bad, sorry for that.

My DB is working really fine, because when i put the dates in the query, the page give me all i need, but i need to choose a variable date range from inputs and shows in a `<div>`, i'm passing the dates with AJAX to a PHP file and then to the query.

Now the error:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for CRUD::MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha(), 
called in C:\xampp\htdocs\personas\source\php\mostrar_reporte_rango_fecha.php 
on line 16 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\personas\source\php\core.php on line 93

Warning: Missing argument 2 for CRUD::MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha(), 
called in C:\xampp\htdocs\personas\source\php\mostrar_reporte_rango_fecha.php
on line 16 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\personas\source\php\core.php on line 93
```

Now the code:

The php file that receive the data looks like this:

```
 elseif (isset($_POST['fecha_inicial']) && isset($_POST['fecha_final'])) {
if(!file_exists("core.php")) {
    die("El archivo core.php no existe o fue movido de su directorio. Contacte a su administrador");
} else {
    require("core.php");
    $fecha_inicial = $_POST['fecha_inicial'];
    $fecha_final = $_POST['fecha_final'];
    $object = new CRUD();
    $object->MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha($fecha_inicial, $fecha_final);
}
}
```

Core.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
class CRUD {
protected $db;
function __construct() { $this->db = DB(); }
function __destruct() { $this->db = null; }

public function MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha($fecha_inicial, $fecha_final) {
    try {
        $q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT E.idEmpleado, R.idRegistro, E.datosEmpleado, R.fecha, C.datosCargo, R.hEntrada, R.hSalida, E.cedulaEmpleado, R.updated_at, R.created_at
                                FROM registro R
                                INNER JOIN empleados E ON R.idEmpleado = E.idEmpleado
                                INNER JOIN cargos C ON R.idCargo = C.idCargo
                                WHERE fecha BETWEEN ':fecha_inicial' AND ':fecha_final'
                                ORDER BY fecha ASC");
        $q->bindParam("fecha_inicial", $fecha_inicial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam("fecha_final", $fecha_final, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->execute();
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        } return $data;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error leyendo tabla de registro: ' . $q->errorCode();
    }
}
```

File i'm using to get result from query and shows in html page.

```
if(!file_exists("core.php")) {
    die("El archivo lib.php no existe o fue movido de su directorio. Contacte a su administrador");
   } else {
   require 'core.php';
   $object = new CRUD();
   $data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Nombres y Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Cedula de Identidad</th>
                        <th>Cargo</th>
                        <th>Entrada</th>
                        <th>Salida</th>
                    </tr>';
    $users = $object->MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha();
    $count = count($users);
    if (count($users) > 0) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
    $FechaPHP = date('d - M', strtotime($user['fecha']));
    //$fechaSQL = $user['fecha'];
    //$newfecha = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fechaSQL));
    if($user['hSalida'] == '00:00:00'){ 
    $user['hSalida'] = ""; 
    $hEntradaSQL = $user['hEntrada'];
    $newhEntrada = date('h:i A', strtotime($hEntradaSQL));
    $data .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $FechaPHP . '</td>
                <td>' . $user['datosEmpleado'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $user['cedulaEmpleado'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $user['datosCargo'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $newhEntrada . '</td>
                <td>' . $user['hSalida'] . '</td>
            </tr>';
    } else {
        $hEntradaSQL = $user['hEntrada'];
        $newhEntrada = date('h:i A', strtotime($hEntradaSQL));
        $hSalidaSQL = $user['hSalida'];    
        $newhSalida = date('h:i A', strtotime($hSalidaSQL));
        $data .= '<tr>
            <td>' . $FechaPHP . '</td>
            <td>' . $user['datosEmpleado'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $user['cedulaEmpleado'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $user['datosCargo'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $newhEntrada . '</td>
            <td>' . $newhSalida . '</td>
            </tr>';
    }
}
} else {
$data .= '<tr><td colspan="6" class="text-center">Nadie se ha registrado hoy!</td></tr>';
 } $data .= '</table>';
 echo $data;
 }
```

Now the ajax file is fine because i'm testing with alerts in every step and it works sending all the data.
The php file that get the data from ajax and send to the core.php works too.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have no values for `fecha_inicial` and `fecha_final` in your $_POST data.  Did you send a POST request to the page with those parameters?

Comment: `$users = $object->MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha();` You can't make that call without passing arguments.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin it really looks like the 2 variables are empty, but i test with javascript alerts in every step of the send process until the function call, the `$object->MostrarRegistrosRangoFecha($fecha_inicial, $fecha_final);` send the data to the function, but the data don't reach the query.

Comment: @PatrickQ i tried make that call with the variables inside and set them with NULL values, but still don't work.